# Deploying Discord bot with Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

Hello I am trying to deploy my first bot using Heroku using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uH3nWjql2IE&t=157s) tutorial. I have managed to push my code to the app but after adding my config.json 'token' to the app and starting the worker I am getting this:

```
2022-10-23T04:55:31.815878+00:00 app[Worker.1]: Node.js v18.11.0
2022-10-23T04:55:31.927217+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-23T04:55:31.983366+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-10-23T04:55:31.986264+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-23T04:55:34.526205+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node ./src/bot.js`
2022-10-23T04:55:35.356859+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-10-23T04:55:36.599794+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413725+00:00 app[Worker.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413733+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   throw err;
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413733+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   ^
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/bot.js'
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413734+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413735+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413735+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413735+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413748+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413749+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   requireStack: []
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413749+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413755+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2022-10-23T04:55:36.413755+00:00 app[Worker.1]: Node.js v18.11.0
2022-10-23T04:55:36.653228+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "mudbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MUDbot",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Shirish Sarkar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.5.0",
    "env": "^0.0.2"
  }
}
```

I don't understand what the issue is. Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: this solved my issue: first my procfile was pointing to an incorrect path. Then I found that Heroku appears to only accept .env variables, not config.json, which is the default config on discord's bot guide (they ought to change that!). After updating those things and adding the vars to Heroku's config, the bot is up and running.

Comment: Have you tried any Heroku alternatives? I ran across this the other day: https://pipedream.com/apps/render/integrations/discord-bot

Comment: I originally started with glitch.com which proved to be a dud since it doesn’t have the latest node or discord.js packages. But since I got Heroku working, I’m sticking with it for now!

Answer (score 1):

this solved my issue: first my procfile was pointing to an incorrect path. Then I found that Heroku appears to only accept .env variables, not config.json, which is the default config on discord's bot guide (they ought to change that!). After updating those things and adding the vars to Heroku's config, the bot is up and running.